# 'int' object has no attribute 'mouse_x' referring to self.mx

Tags: python, pygame, sprite

I have a mouse sprite that updates the x and y positions of the mouse each iteration of the game loop, but I am not quite sure what the error message found below: "'int' object has no attribute 'mouse_x', seems like its referring to 'self' as an int object, and 'mouse_x' to be its attribute?

```
import pygame


class mouse_sprite(pygame.sprite.Sprite):


    def __init__(self, x, y, screen):
        self.screen = screen
        self.mouse_x = x
        self.mouse_y = y

        self.update_rect(self.mx, self.my)

    def update_rect(self):
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(self.mouse_x, self.mouse_y, 1, 1)

    def update(self, x=None, y=None, screen=None):
        **#ERROR: 'int' object has no attribute 'mouse_x' Line 24: self.mouse_x = x**
        if x is not None:
            self.mouse_x = x

        if my is not None:
            self.mouse_y = y

        if screen is not None:
            self.screen = screen

        self.update_rect()

mouse = mouse_sprite
mx, my = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
mouse.update(mx, my)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not creating a new object. You're just calling class method like a static method

Instead of

```
mouse = mouse_sprite
```

do

```
object = mouse_sprite(...)  # Pass init parameters
object.update(...)          # Pass method parameters
```

When you call a method on created object, first parameter gets passed as `self`. In your case, you've not created a new object so the first parameter `mx` is getting assigned to `self` which of type int. And it doesn't have field `mouse_x`.